# Prediction On Seasonal Data

Tags: python, r, data-analysis, data-modeling, prediction

I am looking to predict values based on seasonal data. Bonuses are paid quarterly/ annually/ monthly and amount usually goes up after couple of time periods. Data is given below. I have converted the Bonus event as the numerical value (Yes = 1, No = 0). I have tried using Excel's forecast functions but it was not useful.

Is there a package with the help of which I can predict Next Month & Amount of Bonus? where the recent data points have higher weightage than the older ones.

My dataset has about 10 years worth of data and about 10,000 personnel. So, it is not possible to predict both Month and Amount manually. I am trying to predict the next Bonus Month and Amount.

| Date | Bonus | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-15 | 0 | 000 |
| Feb-15 | 0 | 000 |
| Mar-15 | 1 | 100 |
| Apr-15 | 0 | 000 |
| May-15 | 0 | 000 |
| Jun-15 | 1 | 100 |
| Jul-15 | 0 | 000 |
| Aug-15 | 0 | 000 |
| Sep-15 | 1 | 145 |
| Oct-15 | 0 | 000 |
| Nov-15 | 0 | 000 |
| Dec-15 | 1 | 145 |
| Jan-16 | 0 | 000 |
| Feb-16 | 0 | 000 |
| Mar-16 | 1 | 145 |
| Apr-16 | 0 | 000 |
| May-16 | 1 | 150 |
| Jun-16 | 0 | 000 |
| Jul-16 | 0 | 000 |
| Aug-16 | 1 | 150 |
| Sep-16 | 0 | 000 |
| Oct-16 | 0 | 000 |
| Nov-16 | 1 | 150 |
| Dec-16 | 0 | 000 |

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Pandas package (https://pypi.org/project/pandas/). The problem you have is fundamental time series analysis as far as I can tell and there are many guides online on how to implement it (just search for ARIMA pandas).